# Hanning (von Hann) window

Tags: java, android, signal-processing

```
public short[] HanningWindow(short[] signal_in ,int pos ,int size)
{
    for (int i= pos; i < pos+size; i++)
    {
        signal_in[i] = (short) ((signal_in[i]) * ( 0.5 * (1-Math.cos( (2 * Math.PI * i) /    (size - 1))))) ;
    }
    return signal_in;
}
```

I am trying to use it over

```
pos = (ring+delay*frame_rate*frame_size)%(frame_size*(frame_rate+1));
num = record.read(lin,pos,frame_size);           

GGSpecSub tempSpecSub = new GGSpecSub();
lin = tempSpecSub.HanningWindow(lin, pos, frame_size);
```

It's my first time using real-time DSP - please tell me if this is the right way to apply a Hanning window to a signal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it needs to be more like this:

```
public short[] HanningWindow(short[] signal_in, int pos, int size)
{
    for (int i = pos; i < pos + size; i++)
    {
        int j = i - pos; // j = index into Hann window function
        signal_in[i] = (short) (signal_in[i] * 0.5 * (1.0 - Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * j / size)));
    }
    return signal_in;
}
```

Comment: pos is the position where the Android is reading using AudioRecord.read() function. what i'm doing here is giving the whole signal_in.length which is 11776 and reading only 512 samples from it. why do i have to do  int j = i - pos?

Comment: `j` needs to take values from `0` to `size - 1` so that the cosine function operates ver the range `[0..2π)`.

Comment: No - `i` is the sample index - it runs from `pos` to `pos + size - 1`. You can't use this value for the Hann window - you need a 0-based index, hence the need for `j`.

Comment: ok i get it, if u can plz look at the rest of the algorithm. thank you very much http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602126/spectral-subtraction-android-those-are-the-hanning-window-method-and-the-globa

Comment: I looked and I've made a suggestion - it looks like you're currently out of your depth with both DSP and programming and need to take a step back and understand how this algorithm works before trying to do any more coding.

Comment: hi thanks, since this is the only thing i need to implement for my university project. i would appricicate any Tip, i do not fully understand the algorithm. this is why i'm asking here for directions. i would thank you for any help you may give me. my project is about Android based DSP

Comment: Spend some time on understanding the algorithm or you will never get the implementation right.

Comment: hi @Paul R can you please look at my question i'm learning Matlab to java conversion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367532/spectral-subtraction-in-java-using-jmathlib

Comment: @Gilad: Sorry - no - I don't do Java.

Comment: hi Paul, i'm working very hard for 2 weeks on Matlab and the implementation of the Algorithm like u suggested, i have learned what LPF is, how to recognize the noise Spectrum and how does the Algorithm works in Matlab including doing some sampling of my own. working on Matlab 2011Ra as we speak. as far as Java and real-time implementations i'm struggling with it , please give me an advice where to continue my studying ? except pressing F1 for help in Matlab ... thank you