# Hanning window parameters

Tags: java, javascript, android, signal-processing

Using the following link on stack overflow , i got the code to doing a hanning window :

[Hanning (von Hann) window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600515/hanning-von-hann-window)

```
    public short[] HanningWindow(short[] signal_in, int pos, int size)
   {
    for (int i = pos; i < pos + size; i++)
   {
    int j = i - pos; // j = index into Hann window function
    signal_in[i] = (short) (signal_in[i] * 0.5 * (1.0 - Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * j / size)));
    }
    return signal_in;
   }
```

My issue is i dont how to deal with the parameters:

I get that signal_in is the signal i'm doing windowing on,,,, but what is meant by pos and size???

Comment: You get it in the comments from the post you linked.

Comment: no,, actually in the post i linked, it says what pos is, but not size,,, but even pos, i dont get what he means!

Comment: Where the signal is (or where you want to apply the Hanning window). `pos` = index of `signal_in` of the first sample to process, `size` = number of samples to process. In case you want to process all `signal_in` just set `pos = 0` and `size = signal_in.length`. Window will be shaped from `pos` to `pos + size` regardless how long the input array is.

Comment: You welcome! (3 to go)